# Short question about cin and input buffer

Tags: c++

So, after learning a bit about the input stream and how the extraction operator works, is it basically okay to say this about the following code?

```
string a;
cin >> a;
```

This will basically extract whatever there is in the input stream, but if the stream is empty it basically asks the user to input something? Like is that right?

I used to think `cin` gives access to the input stream and the user can just types whatever and that gets extracted, but now that I understand it a bit more, is what I said true? It tries to extract something from the stream, but if it sees nothing there then it'll ask the user for input?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  They will explain stuff like this in the books.

Comment: The expression `cin >> a;` does not **prompt** a user.  The `cin` stream may wait for {additional} User input.

Comment: Why are you asking me to get a good c++ book haha I mean from what I see here what I said is basically right? I was just making sure. Is what I said wrong? I already have a book but I just wanted to make sure I understand this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) is an object instance of the [`std::istream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) class, which has a [`std::streambuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) object associated with it.

`std::streambuf` contains a memory buffer inside of it.

By default, `std::cin` uses an implementation of `std::streambuf` that reads from the calling process's `STDIN` stream.

When [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) reads from `std::cin`, `std::cin` then reads data from its `streambuf`, which in turn reads from its memory buffer.

If that memory buffer does not contain enough data to satisfy the read, `std::streambuf` will read from its own input stream, placing new data into its memory buffer, repeating as needed until the requested read is satisfied.  In your example, it will read from `STDIN`.

If that input stream does not have enough data to satisfy the read, it will wait for data to arrive, ie when the user types something into the console terminal. Or, if `STDIN` is redirected, when data arrives on the assigned pipe, or the pipe is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The `cin` has a buffer (input stream).  The `operator>>` will extract from the stream until the requirements are satisfied.  If more input is required, `cin` will wait for the User to input more data (into the stream).